# How to center multiple divs in center?

Tags: css

How to align these boxes in top middle of viewport?  Without using flex property, Can these boxes be centered?

```css
div.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100px;
}
div.div1 {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, red, green);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red, green);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, red, green);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, red, green);
  background: linear-gradient(left, red, green);
}
div.div2 {
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(top, circle, red, yellow, green);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top, circle, red, yellow, green);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(top, circle, red, yellow, green);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(top, circle, red, yellow, green);
  background: radial-gradient(top, circle, red, yellow, green);
}
div.div3 {
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(top, ellipse, red, yellow, green);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top, ellipse, red, yellow, green);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(top, ellipse, red, yellow, green);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(top, ellipse, red, yellow, green);
  background: radial-gradient(top, ellipse, red, yellow, green);
}
```

```html
<div class="box div1">Box</div>
<div class="box div2">Box</div>
<div class="box div3">Box</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of body you should wrap all 3 divs to a main div
See updated code here:

```
 <div class='main'>
   <div class="box div1">Box</div>
   <div class="box div2">Box</div>
   <div class="box div3">Box</div>  
</div>

div.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100px;
}
div.div1 {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, red, green);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red, green);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, red, green);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, red, green);
  background: linear-gradient(left, red, green);
}
div.div2 {
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(top, circle, red, yellow, green);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top, circle, red, yellow, green);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(top, circle, red, yellow, green);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(top, circle, red, yellow, green);
  background: radial-gradient(top, circle, red, yellow, green);
}
div.div3 {
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(top, ellipse, red, yellow, green);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top, ellipse, red, yellow, green);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(top, ellipse, red, yellow, green);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(top, ellipse, red, yellow, green);
  background: radial-gradient(top, ellipse, red, yellow, green);
}
.main{
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can just add:

```
body {
  text-align: center
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center
}
div.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100px;
}
div.div1 {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, red, green);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red, green);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, red, green);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, red, green);
  background: linear-gradient(left, red, green);
}
div.div2 {
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(top, circle, red, yellow, green);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top, circle, red, yellow, green);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(top, circle, red, yellow, green);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(top, circle, red, yellow, green);
  background: radial-gradient(top, circle, red, yellow, green);
}
div.div3 {
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(top, ellipse, red, yellow, green);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top, ellipse, red, yellow, green);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(top, ellipse, red, yellow, green);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(top, ellipse, red, yellow, green);
  background: radial-gradient(top, ellipse, red, yellow, green);
}
```

```html
<div class="box div1">Box</div>
<div class="box div2">Box</div>
<div class="box div3">Box</div>
```

Comment: It is working. But `text-align` wording is a bit misleading. I need div elements to be centered. Do we use `text-align` for text purely?

Comment: Well, I didn't invent the syntax and no, it centers the content, not just text. [The text-align CSS property describes how inline content like text is aligned in its parent block element.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)

Comment: @overexchange the rule is for inline elements., text is a inline element as inline-block..and yes maybe the word be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Set a container with the rule `text-align: center;`

**HTML**

```
<div class="text-center">
    <div class="box div1">Box</div> 
    <div class="box div2">Box</div>
    <div class="box div3">Box</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.text-center{
display: block;
text-align: center;
}
```